# Error uploading text file in android(server could not understand the request the browser sent)

Tags: android

' 
               try
        {
            String upurl = ;
            String path = getFilesDir().getPath();
            String filename= dq.fetchfilename();
            filename =filename.replaceFirst("M", "T");
            path= path.concat("/"+filename);

```
        File file = new File(path);

           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(upurl);

InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
            reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
            reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 String str= inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            //Do something with response...
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
            {
                bf=false;
            }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        bf=false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

    }
 '
//error while uploading a text file onto the server 
//bad request server could not understand the request sent by your browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Code-

```
public class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object>
{
  URL connectURL;
  String params;
  String responseString;
  String fileName;
  byte[] dataToServer;
  FileInputStream fileInputStream;
  private int serverResponseCode;

  private String serverResponseMessage;

  private static final String TAG = "Uploader";


  public void setUrlAndFile(String urlString, File fileName)
  {
     Log.d(TAG,"StartUploader");

  try
  {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    connectURL = new URL(urlString);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    e.getStackTrace();
    publishProgress(e.toString());

  }
  this.fileName = fileName.getAbsolutePath()+".txt";

}

synchronized void doUpload()
{
  String lineEnd = "\r\n";
  String twoHyphens = "--";
  String boundary = "*****";
  Log.d(TAG,"lv1");

 try
{
    Log.d(TAG,"doUpload");
    publishProgress("Uploading...");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    DataOutputStream dos  = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"Uploaded\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    Log.d(TAG,"LvA");
    Log.d(TAG,twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd + ";Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"Uploaded\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    int maxBufferSize = 1024;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0, bufferSize);
    Log.d(TAG,"LvB");
    while(bytesRead > 0)
    {

        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    fileInputStream.close();
   dos.flush();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    int ch;
    Log.d(TAG,"LvC");
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    while((ch=is.read()) != -1)
    {
        buff.append((char)ch);
    }
   // publishProgress(buff.toString());
    dos.close();


 // Responses from the server (code and message)
    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
   // Log.d(TAG,"Buffer "+buff.toString());

    Log.d(TAG,"Server Response "+serverResponseMessage);
}

  catch(Exception e)
  {
    e.getStackTrace();
     publishProgress(e.toString());
  }
}

 @Override
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) 
 {
   Log.d(TAG,"lv1a");
   doUpload();
   Log.d(TAG,"Uploading Completed! Path: "+connectURL);

   return null;
  }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
 {
  //this.info.setText(progress[0]);
    Log.d("Progress", progress[0]);
  }


}
```

PHP Code-

```
< ?php

  $file_path = "uploads/";

  $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
     echo "success";
  } else{
     echo "fail";
  }
  ? >
```

Also you can check  [link 1](http://www.codepuppet.com/2013/03/26/android-uploading-a-file-to-a-php-server/)
[link 2](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/file-upload-on-php-server-in-android.html)

Comment: <?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 echo true;
 } 
 else {
 //echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 echo false;
 }
 ?>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head><body><h1>Bad Request</h1><p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br /></p><p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Errorerror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p></body></html>

Comment: conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);  //its giving null pointer exception at this line

Comment: what you passed to connectURL.

Comment: with the http as prefix

Comment: could you help me obtain the filename ,the text file is stored in data/data/files/test.txt

Comment: try this.  context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/test.txt"

Comment: no errors getting the response code as 302 ...response msg as FOUND